# Positioning <button class="close"> in Bootstrap dropdown element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to position a Bootstrap close button within a dropdown element (also Bootstrap).

```
  <div id="contextmenu" class="dropdown clearfix" style="position: absolute;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block;">
      <li><a href="#">Text <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

That thing floats right, but appears mispositioned in Firefox (first screenshot). Chrome renders it as intended (second screenshot).

[image: Close button within dropdown element in Firefox]

[image: Close button within dropdown element in Firefox]

Is there any way to make Firefox render it correctly (i.e. as Chrome does)?

Comment: Simply put the button at the `li` start before the "Text". There are prettiest solutions which require using CSS.

Comment: This does indeed position the button somewhat correctly. Unfortunately, Firefox lets the x hug the bottom despite `vertical-align: middle;`. Any ideas?

Comment: Please upload your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net so we can take a look

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NMUAc/

Comment: I'm on FF 23 and it looks alright

Comment: I am on FF23 also. That is what it looks like for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nklqW.png

Compared to the Chrome screenshot from my question, the x is aligned to the bottom. This is quite problematic, because the alignment becomes confusing with multiple elements in the list.

Comment: The proposed solution [seems to work in Firefox](http://jsfiddle.net/websiter/tp8vn7as/). Answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to know without more context regarding your CSS, but one solution might be to check that the position the of the 'x' is positioned absolutely relative to your containing `<li>`.

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-menu li {
  ..
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu li .close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has no effect. I have no own CSS that affects any of the elements involved. It's all Bootstrap v2.3.1.

Comment: Well, it does kinda work... for Firefox. It's what I tried first. Unfortunately, it makes it misaligned in Chrome (and probably other Browsers). This might just be some Firefox weirdness...

Comment: Yeah you could isolate that rule to Mozilla with this hack @-moz-document url-prefix() { //place code here // }, but, ya know, hacks :)

Comment: Had to use a hack, adjusting the line-height